# Date conversion but not with expected output

Tags: java

```
String S = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(myDate);
```

The Date passed here in myDate is 15 Oct 2010(not the exact format),actually a time stamp which of type Date in java.

but the output in string S is `20100115` and **not** `20101015` as expected.Can anyone provide the input.Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Then myDate, your DB is corrupt. Do a `myDate.toString()` and you'll see.

Comment: did you debug to ensure that myDate is correct ? Your `DateFormat` looks good.

Comment: This is almost definitely a case of the [XY-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  You think that the problem is with the `SimpleDateFormat`, but it's probably in how you got `myDate`.  Please post relevant code.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/vNSdeL

Comment: Hey Guys Sorry the value in between was getting changed to 15th jan 2010.Anyways Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with myDate.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,15);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,9);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2010);

    Date date = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());    
    String S = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd").format(date);
    System.out.println(S);
```

The console says:

```
2010:10:15
```

Which is correct. Please note that for some reason months start indexing at 0 (!), so it's 0-11 (january to december).